# Where is cf/README? It's supposed to be with the configuration files

Tags: sendmail

The main documentation for configuring sendmail is in a file at sendmail/cf/README. For some reason it isn't here on my 18.04 server.

Note that this file is referred to in other documentation within the sendmail/cf directories.

Comment: Have you installed `sendmail-doc` - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=sendmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the sendmail documentation package?  `sendmail-doc`

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sendmail-doc

> powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent (documentation)

Comment: Now the question is why they are separate, but that's not really a question for ask ubuntu.

Comment: I think (ie. this is my opinion) is that most users of the package already know what they want to do, and won't touch the documentation as don't need it. They'd prefer the package 'light' so the machine remains light (esp. if it'll be containerized, or used along with other VMs on real hardware).  Separating the doco allows those that want to grab it also (you would have been suggested to download it at install; see https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sendmail) but not get it if unwanted.

Comment: Yeah the container thing I hadn't thought about. Makes sense.